# c# clickonce deployment: how to rename 'Application Files'?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, clickonce

I'm new to clickonce so i'm trying to use public hosting for the first steps.
I'm expreriencing a problem, which is:

Ftp server rejects folders with spaces in their names, so

`ftp://.../ProgramName/Application Files/`

can't be deployed. I've figured out the issue: VS 2010 cannot upload folders with spaces in names to the server. I googled the problem and found this [post](http://wallism.wordpress.com/2010/06/09/clickonce-master-build/), which suggests to change Microsoft.Common.targets file a little( replace "Application Files" with "ApplicationFiles". I did that, but now visual studio break whith error on deployment:

> Publish failed with the following
>   error: Could not find a part of the
>   path
>   'E:...\bin\Release\app.publish\Application Files\'

that's true, because

> \bin\Release\app.publish\Application
>   Files\

doesnt exist, 
but

> \bin\Release\app.publish\ApplicationFiles\

does.That fits the changes i've made to .targets file, but VS is still "doing it wrong".

What else can i do to deploy my app on server that can't except names like "Application Files" ?

Thanks in advance, Ilya.

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering what happens if you put %20 in the link where the space is? (No way to change it in ClickOnce that I know of.)